# Menu logos are in the center of the div but not the titles - Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been trying to create a responsive menu for the mobile browser of my site and it has four links. I have given `25%` width for each of them. The problem is, although its logos stay center their titles don't. You can notice for the snippet that the titles are not in the center of their `div`.

What is the problem here? What am I doing wrong? Can you suggest how can I keep these titles center as well?

this is the current state:
[image]

I'm trying to make it something like this:
[image]

The snippet:

```css
.menu {
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 0;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #434A54;
 color: white;
 font-size: 12px;
 padding-top: 7px;
}

a.main-link:link,
a.main-link:visited {
 background-color: #434A54;
 color: white;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 25%;
}

.logo {
 width: 24px;
 height: 24px;
 margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container menu">
   <div class="row">
      <a href="start.html" class="main-link">
         <div class="col-3"> <img src="http://diylogodesigns.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/google-logo-icon-PNG-Transparent-Background.png" class="logo"/> <br>
            LINK1 
         </div>
      </a>
      <a href="calculator-home.html" class="main-link">
         <div class="col-3"> <img src="http://diylogodesigns.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/google-logo-icon-PNG-Transparent-Background.png" class="logo"/> <br>
            LINK222 
         </div>
      </a>
      <a href="contact.html" class="main-link">
         <div class="col-3"> <img src="http://diylogodesigns.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/google-logo-icon-PNG-Transparent-Background.png" class="logo"/> <br>
            LINK33333 
         </div>
      </a>
      <a href="about.html" class="main-link">
         <div class="col-3"> <img src="http://diylogodesigns.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/google-logo-icon-PNG-Transparent-Background.png" class="logo"/> <br>
            LINK4444444 
         </div>
      </a>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Columns should be direct child of rows.

Add `text center` class to the columns. Put the anchor tag inside of columns and make it `display:block`. And the image and menu title should be placed inside the anchor tag.

```css
/*This css is not required. */
img{
  width:25px;
  height:25px;
}

a.main-link:link,
a.main-link:visited {
 text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-3 text-center">
    <a href="start.html" class="main-link d-block">
      <img src="http://diylogodesigns.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/google-logo-icon-PNG-Transparent-Background.png" class="logo " />
      <div> LINK1 </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3 text-center">
    <a href="start.html" class="main-link d-block">
      <img src="http://diylogodesigns.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/google-logo-icon-PNG-Transparent-Background.png" class="logo " />
      <div> LINK1 </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3 text-center">
    <a href="start.html" class="main-link d-block">
      <img src="http://diylogodesigns.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/google-logo-icon-PNG-Transparent-Background.png" class="logo " />
      <div> LINK1 </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It seems the better option, can you please update it as a working snippet?

Comment: @Ashonko Updated answer

Comment: Thank you very much. It is a smart and better approach.

Answer (score 1):

If you change the `html` code and add the image before the text inside the anchor tag then add `text-align: center` you'll get the same result

check my code:

```css
.menu {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #434A54;
  color: white;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding-top: 7px;
}

.main-link {
  text-align: center
}

a.main-link:link,
a.main-link:visited {
  background-color: #434A54;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
}

.logo {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container menu">
  <div class="row">
    <a href="start.html" class="main-link">
      <img src="http://diylogodesigns.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/google-logo-icon-PNG-Transparent-Background.png" class="logo" /><br />
      <span class="col-3">LINK1
   </span>
    </a>
    <a href="calculator-home.html" class="main-link">
      <img src="http://diylogodesigns.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/google-logo-icon-PNG-Transparent-Background.png" class="logo" /> <br>
      <span class="col-3">LINK222
   </span>
    </a>
    <a href="contact.html" class="main-link">
      <img src="http://diylogodesigns.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/google-logo-icon-PNG-Transparent-Background.png" class="logo" /> <br>
      <span class="col-3">LINK33333
   </span>
    </a>
    <a href="about.html" class="main-link">
      <img src="http://diylogodesigns.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/google-logo-icon-PNG-Transparent-Background.png" class="logo" /><br />
      <span class="col-3">LINK4444444
   </span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion. Cheers.